# Select2 multiple doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery-select2

I have multiple select drop down which should to add selected items as rows in data table, and remove them from data table when item is unselected. It look like a this image. [image: Bill column added in table]. When i want to add other column which is before first selected is ok, but when wanted column is after first selected this is not possible.  [image: Bill and web are added but status not.]. [image: Values in select drop down are]. I have this code in my script.

```js
$('#displayInTable').select2({
  placeholder: "Display in table",
  allowClear: true
});
$('#displayInTable').change(function() {

  table = $("#analysisTable").DataTable();
});

$('#displayInTable').on('select2:select', function() {
  //table.column(0).visible(true);
  var selected_value = $('#displayInTable').val();
  table.column(selected_value).visible(true);
}).trigger('change');

$('#displayInTable').on("select2:unselecting", function(e) {
  var unselected_value = $('#displayInTable').val();
  table.column($(this).val()).visible(false);
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" />

<select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" id="displayInTable" data-placeholder="Display in table" style="width: 100%;">
  <option value="4">e-mail</option>
  <option value="5">web</option>
  <option value="6">bill</option>
  <option value="7">savings</option>
  <option value="8">status</option>
</select>
```

Also data-placeholder doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure about DataTable but you trigger the change of your select (not the table) with `.trigger('change')` it's essentially like `$('#displayInTable').trigger('change')`. Also the `$('#displayInTable').change` event will also be called with every change (select/unselect).

Comment: From the API doc of [DataTables column](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column()) it seems you can only select a single column, but your select value can contain multiple values, so that might not work to change the visibility of your columns. So try to use `table.columns` instead of `table.column`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `e.params.data.id` to get the value of the selected or unselected option because `$('#displayInTable').val()` returns the values of every selected options. Also use the unselect event instead of unselecting.

```js
$('#displayInTable').select2({
  placeholder: "Display in table",
  allowClear: true
});
$('#displayInTable').change(function() {
  table = $("#analysisTable").DataTable();
});

$('#displayInTable').on('select2:select', function(e) {
  var selected_value = Number(e.params.data.id);
  table.column(selected_value).visible(true);
});

$('#displayInTable').on("select2:unselect", function(e) {
  var unselected_value = Number(e.params.data.id);
  table.column(unselected_value).visible(false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" />

<select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" id="displayInTable" data-placeholder="Display in table" style="width: 100%;">
  <option value="4">e-mail</option>
  <option value="5">web</option>
  <option value="6">bill</option>
  <option value="7">savings</option>
  <option value="8">status</option>
</select>
```